# Find symbol's font slot

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

Afte reading the post about [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font) I was curious how the people know the symbol's font slot, like `"80` in that example.

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsubset}{3}{matha}{"80}
```

I'd like to do the similar replacement for `\cap` and `\cup`, but I don't know their slots.

Comment: if as there you are copying the character from an existing font setup then simply take it from the package the line you quote has the comment `% Define a subset character from that font (from mathabx.dcl)` that file also has the lines `\DeclareMathSymbol{\cap}           {2}{matha}{"58}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\cup}           {2}{matha}{"59}`

Comment: I like using the `fonttable` package for such things, for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/486288/where-can-i-find-how-to-tex-symbols-for-different-fonts/486292#486292

Comment: In the linked question, you could look at the file "mathabx.dcl" to be found in your TexLive distribution (in general in a hidden folder), and here it is: "\DeclareMathSymbol{\subset}        {3}{matha}{"80}"

Answer (score 2):

You can, in order of decreasing convenience:

- Use `unicode-math`, where you can replace any math symbol with `\setmathfont[range=\symbol]{...}`. Many OpenType math fonts have variants in stylistic sets.
- Check the package documentation for a font table.
- Check whether it uses [a standard LaTeX encoding.](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf)  If it does, it probably has files with names like`oms*.fd` and `omx*.fd`.
- Search the `.sty` file for the symbol and copy-paste the commands needed to define it.  Usually this is `\DeclareSymbolFont`, and sometimes `\SetSymbolFont` for `bold`, followed by `\DeclareMathSymbol`.
- [Make font tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131058/how-do-i-know-what-symbols-characters-are-available-in-a-font-package) for all the package’s symbol fonts and look for the symbol in there.